# Asp.net mvc web application dropdowns not working (sometimes) on MAC client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, combobox, dropdown

I developed a ASP.net MVC application (.Net Framework 4.8) and deployed it on a windows server.
For the most part, the website works fine, but I am getting complaints that dropdowns do not work (sometimes) on MAC clients. Although, the issue happens infrequently, I am wondering what the reason could be. Any thoughts or ideas?

## Here is the model definition of the dropdown in question:

```
Private _trans_opaque As List(Of SelectListItem)
<Display(Name:="Transparent/Opaque")>
Public Property Trans_opaque() As List(Of SelectListItem)
    Get
        Return _trans_opaque
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of SelectListItem))
        _trans_opaque = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _trans_opaque_value As String
<Display(Name:="Transparent/Opaque")>
<Required(ErrorMessage:="Transparent/Opaque is required")>
Public Property Trans_opaque_value() As String
    Get
        Return _trans_opaque_value
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _trans_opaque_value = value
    End Set
End Property
```

## **Here is the HTML markup:**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Trans_opaque, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.Trans_opaque_value, Model.Trans_opaque, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}, .Style = "height: 30px;width:100%"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Trans_opaque_value, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group hide">
        @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Trans_opaque_value, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Trans_opaque_value, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Trans_opaque_value, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})*@
        </div>
    </div>
```